# how to update and insert on specific condition in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, dml

I have one table name 'test':

```
create table test(main_mix_number varchar(20),formulation_mix_number varchar(20),param1 varchar(20),param2 varchar(20));
```

It has below row:

```
insert into test(formulation_mix_number,param1,param2) values ('101A','abc','xyz');
+-----------------+------------------------+--------+--------+
| main_mix_number | formulation_mix_number | param1 | param2 |
+-----------------+------------------------+--------+--------+
| NULL            | 101A                   | abc    | xyz    |
+-----------------+------------------------+--------+--------+
```

Now,

```
if number of row where 'main_mix_number' is 'NULL' equals 1 then I want to update the row 

else if number of rows where 'main_mix_number' is 'NULL' greater than 1 then I want to update the first row 

else if number of rows where 'main_mix_number' is 'NULL' equals 0 then row insertion took place.
```

So, I have tried the below query:

```
    select (
case when (select count(distinct(formulation_mix_number)) from test where formulation_mix_number='101A' and main_mix_number is NULL)=1 then 
(update test set main_mix_number='1A' where formulation_mix_number='101A') 
when (select count(distinct(formulation_mix_number)) from test where formulation_mix_number='101A' and main_mix_number is NULL)>1 then 
(update test set main_mix_number='1A' where formulation_mix_number='101A' order by formulation_mix_number desc limit 1) 
when (select count(distinct(formulation_mix_number)) from test where formulation_mix_number='101A' and main_mix_number is NULL)=0 then 
(insert into test (main_mix_number,formulation_mix_number,param1,param2) 
select * from (select '1A' as main_mix_number,'101A' as fromulation_mix_number,param1,param2 from test where formulation_mix_number='101A' order by fromulation_mix_number desc limit 1) as tmp 
where not exists (select main_mix_number,formulation_mix_number from test where main_mix_number='1A' and formulation_mix_number='101A')) else NULL end) 
from temp;
```

But as select and update or insert will not going to work together, this query is not working. I know there is another way that I can keep formulation_mix_number and main_mix_number in a separate table and do not mix main_mix_number with formulation_mix_number details.
But due to some reason I am not allowed to add another table in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this needs dynamic sql

> ```
> create table test(main_mix_number varchar(20),formulation_mix_number varchar(20),param1 varchar(20),param2 varchar(20));
> ```

> ```
> insert into test(formulation_mix_number,param1,param2) values ('101A','abc','xyz');
> ```

> ```
>     SELECT 
>     (CASE
>         WHEN
>             (SELECT 
>                     COUNT(DISTINCT (formulation_mix_number))
>                 FROM
>                     test
>                 WHERE
>                     formulation_mix_number = '101A'
>                         AND main_mix_number IS NULL) = 1
>         THEN
>             (@sql:='update test set main_mix_number=\'1A\' where formulation_mix_number=\'101A\'')
>         WHEN
>             (SELECT 
>                     COUNT(DISTINCT (formulation_mix_number))
>                 FROM
>                     test
>                 WHERE
>                     formulation_mix_number = '101A'
>                         AND main_mix_number IS NULL) > 1
>         THEN
>             (@sql:='update test set main_mix_number=\'1A\' where formulation_mix_number=\'101A\' order by formulation_mix_number desc limit 1')
>         WHEN
>             (SELECT 
>                     COUNT(DISTINCT (formulation_mix_number))
>                 FROM
>                     test
>                 WHERE
>                     formulation_mix_number = '101A'
>                         AND main_mix_number IS NULL) = 0
>         THEN
>             (@sql:='insert into test (main_mix_number,formulation_mix_number,param1,param2) 
>             select * from (select \'1A\' as main_mix_number,\'101A\' as fromulation_mix_number,param1,param2 from test where formulation_mix_number=\'101A\' order by fromulation_mix_number desc limit 1) as tmp 
>             where not exists (select main_mix_number,formulation_mix_number from test where main_mix_number=\'1A\' and formulation_mix_number=\'101A\')')
>         ELSE NULL
>     END)
> FROM
>     test
> ```

> ```
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE stmt;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM test
> ```
>
> ```
> main_mix_number | formulation_mix_number | param1 | param2
> :-------------- | :--------------------- | :----- | :-----
> 1A              | 101A                   | abc    | xyz
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fb1dafcd4589504b818c45fcfc95c546)*