# SQL use value main query on CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I'm trying to create a SQL query containing subqueries which are dependent on the value of the main query. So: if the itemId of the main query = 1, then data from table A should be selected, if itemId of the mail query = 2 then different data should be collected.

I was thinking of using let joins, but that returns a lot of 0 data. However cases do not appear to work. Is such selection even possible?

I have the following query right now;

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT fo.ID, fo.typeId FROM feed_order fo
CASE WHEN fo.typeId = 1 THEN (SELECT p.post_title FROM wp_posts p WHERE p.ID = fo.ID) ELSE () END
CASE WHEN fo.typeId = 2 THEN (SELECT t.post_title FROM tests t WHERE t.ID = fo.ID) ELSE () END
");
```

Comment: this question is similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70653932/how-to-update-and-insert-on-specific-condition-in-mysql/70654327#70654327

Comment: @nbk that doesn't seem like logic to me? I'm querying 100 results, and for each one I would need to go through the entire select process?

Comment: *if the itemId of the main query = 1, then data from table A should be selected, if itemId of the mail query = 2 then different data should be collected.* But what if itemId is not in (1,2)?

Comment: Then it is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Outer join and use `COALESCE` to display the value from one table or the other.

```
SELECT
  fo.id,
  fo.typeid,
  COALESCE(p.post_title, t.post_title) AS post_title
FROM feed_order fo
LEFT JOIN wp_posts p ON p.ID = fo.ID AND fo.typeid = 1 
LEFT JOIN tests t ON t.ID = fo.ID AND fo.typeid = 2
ORDER BY fo.id;
```

Comment: The issue presented is a simplification of the actual, meaning there can be 6 tables with different columns (some more than others), so this would not apply unfortunatly.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Just outer join the other tables, too. Use `COALESCE` on all columns you want to select from one table or another. Use the plain column when it comes from one table only (so it will be null when it soesn't apply).